# issue with getDefaultInstance and javax.mail.Session, java.io.InputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have looking around for answer to these two errors, and have not found the solution.

```
Cannot resolve method 'getDefaultInstance' in 'Session'
'MimeMessage(javax.mail.Session, java.io.InputStream)' in 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage' cannot be applied to '(android.se.omapi.Session, android.net.Uri)'
```

Am I missing something as to using the package?

```
public void getBodySignature(Uri uri) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, uri);
        SMIMESigned signedMessage;
        // multipart/signed message
        // two parts- one part for the content that was signed and one part for the actual signature.
        if (msg.isMimeType("multipart/signed")) {
            signedMessage = new SMIMESigned((MimeMultipart) msg.getContent());
        } else if (msg.isMimeType("text/plain") || msg.isMimeType("application/pkcs7-signature")) {
            // in this case the content is wrapped in the signature block.
            signedMessage = new SMIMESigned(msg);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a signed message!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Session` import is the wrong one. Replace the import for `android.se.omapi.Session` with `javax.mail.Session`. If that causes other issues, because you need both imports, then for one of them you to use the fully qualified name. For instance:

```
javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
```

---

The other issue is the `Uri` argument. There is no `MimeMessage` constructor that takes a `URI` or `Uri` argument. I assume that you have an existing message as a file and want to read from it. You'd need to convert the `Uri` to an `InputStream`. I couldn't find anything for that in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri. I'd see if you can get rid of the `Uri` argument completely and replace it with an `InputStream` or something that can be converted to an `InputStream`.